# Which non-google email domains can edit google sites as admins?

Tags: google-classic-sites

I set up a google sites site.

I added some people to administrate it.

I notice that one guy whose email address is his own domain like  tim@blob.com  it lets me add his email address.

Another person that's  gary@hotmail.com  it lets me add him

But then when I try to add  sarah@msn.com it says "Sorry, you cannot share with sarah@msn.com because they do not have a Google Account."

Well, how does it know whether tim@blob.com has a google account. And why does it have no problem with gary@hotmail.com?!

Comment: there is a google sites google group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Google account, one can use a non-google email address.

If a person's non-google domain email address  could be added to administrate a google sites site, it was because they created a google account with that email address.

[image]